# how to adjust to action site ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

when I apply my master page I get this look for my action site ribbon.
[image]

how can I adjust it.

Answer (score 2):

I just need to put this script in my css file

```
    div.ms-MenuUIPopupScreen div.ms-MenuUIPopupInner div.ms-MenuUILarge ul.ms-MenuUIUL li.ms-MenuUIULItem, div.ms-MenuUIPopupScreen div.ms-MenuUIPopupInner div.ms-MenuUI ul.ms-MenuUIUL li.ms-MenuUIULItem {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
margin-top:-21px

    }
```